# Bouncy Castle upgrade to 1.70 is not working

Tags: java, updates, bouncycastle

I have an existing PGP v 1.60 code in project. now I need to update to 1.70 and it's throwing following error while compiling the code after update.

***incompatible types: java.util.Iterator<org.bouncycastle.openpgp.PGPEncryptedData> cannot be converted to java.util.Iterator<org.bouncycastle.openpgp.PGPPublicKeyEncryptedData>***

Getting the error exactly in this line ->  `Iterator<PGPPublicKeyEncryptedData> it = enc.getEncryptedDataObjects();`

Kindly find the code sample below

```
public static void decryptFile(Input in, Output out,Input keyIn, char[] password) {
    Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());
    in = org.bouncycastle.openpgp.PGPUtil.getDecoderStream(in);
    KeyFingerPrintCalculator calc = new JcaKeyFingerprintCalculator();
    PGPObjectFactory pgpF = new PGPObjectFactory(in,calc);
    PGPEncryptedDataList enc;

    Object o = pgpF.nextObject();
    if (o instanceof PGPEncryptedDataList) {
        enc = (PGPEncryptedDataList) o;
    } else {
        enc = (PGPEncryptedDataList) pgpF.nextObject();
    }

    Iterator<PGPPublicKeyEncryptedData> it = enc.getEncryptedDataObjects(); //getting error here
    PGPPrivateKey key1 = null;
    PGPPublicKeyEncryptedData key2 = null;
}
```

can someone help me here please.

Comment: Sounds like you have 2 different versions of the library in t eclass path

Comment: @Jens Can you please tell me little clear where exactly I need to check for that library. I am using Eclipse and Maven for my project

Comment: use `mvn dependency:tree` and look if you find more than one version for the bouncy castle library

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The return type of `getEncryptedDataObjects` has changed apparently. The line with the error should be changed to:

```
Iterator<PGPEncryptedData> it = enc.getEncryptedDataObjects();
```

`PGPPublicKeyEncryptedData` is one type (i.e. subclass) of `PGPEncryptedData` but later versions of the API support also returning data of type `PGPSymmetricKeyEncryptedData` (with two further subtypes), so the iterator allows both types to be returned.

If you want to then process only the `PGPPublicKeyEncryptedData` entries from the iterator (to follow your old code's functionality), you can use `instanceof` e.g.:

```
Iterator<PGPEncryptedData> it = enc.getEncryptedDataObjects();
while (it.hasNext())
{
    PGPEncryptedData encryptedData = it.next();
    if (encryptedData instanceof PGPPublicKeyEncryptedData)
    {
        PGPPublicKeyEncryptedData pkEncryptedData = (PGPPublicKeyEncryptedData)encryptedData;

        // Process pkEncryptedData as needed.
    }
}
```